# Why is IB improperly displaying my dynamic prototype table view cells

Tags: interface-builder, xcode7

After upgrading to Xcode 7.1, IB no longer displays my table view cells correctly. My table view has 11 dynamic prototype cells defined. The cells in the screen shot are partially visible when the table is scrolled all the way to the top (in IB).  Normally, I could just select the table and scroll to see the other cells.  Now they are partially visible, or not visible at all.  Is there some new setting that I'm missing?

[image]